# Removing OnPremise Shared Mailbox

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

Below is the script I am trying to execute to remove Shared Mailboxes. We have on-prem as well as oncloud shared mailboxex, the below script works fine for oncloud shared mailboxes, but it does not work for on-prem, even though it shows successful execution.

Should I be using Remove-ADUser instead of Remove-RemoteMailbox?

```js
Try{
$SharedMailboxUPN = $payload.sharedMailboxUPN
$isOnPrem = ""
#Connect to Exchange-Online
Try
{ #FIND OUT If Shared Mailbox is On-Prem or OnCloud
$isOnPrem = Get-Mailbox -Identity $SharedMailboxUPN | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RemoteRecipientType
}
Catch
{
    #ERROR MESSAGE GOES HERE
}
if($isOnPrem -eq "Migrated, SharedMailbox") #OnPrem Mailbox
{
$sessionCheck = Get-PSSession
##### Connect to Exchange On-Prem Powershell #####
    if ($sessionCheck -eq $null)
    {
        $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://$TargetServer/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $cred
        Import-PSSession $Session
    }
}
Try 
{
Remove-RemoteMailbox -Identity $SharedMailboxUPN -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop #Shows result as Success, but mailbox is not removed for some reason

Remove-ADUser -Identity $SharedMailboxUPN #SHOULD I USE this instead??

}
Catch 
{
     #ERROR MESSAGE GOES HERE
}
}
else #oncloud mailbox
{
Try
{
     #Connect to ExchangeOnline
    Remove-Mailbox -Identity $SharedMailboxUPN -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
   
}
Catch
{
     #ERROR MESSAGE GOES HERE
}
}    
}
}
Catch
{
 #ERROR MESSAGE GOES HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Remove-RemoteMailbox` will only work for your cloud shared mailboxes, you would want `Remove-Mailbox` to remove on prem shared mailboxes. Using `Remove-ADUser` will remove the object but you should really use the Exchange cmdlets to do this or you could end up with unexpected results like orphaned mailboxes etc

Comment: So Jonathan, the documentation for the `Remove-RemoteMailbox` says that it should work for on-prem objects only, that is why I am using this for on-prem.

Comment: @SumitPandey Not quite, it says `This cmdlet is available only in on-premises Exchange.

Use the Remove-RemoteMailbox cmdlet to remove a mail-enabled user in the on-premises Active Directory and the associated mailbox in the cloud-based service.`

Comment: @notjustme Sorry, If I am getting this wrong, so you are suggesting that I should be able to use `Remove-Mailbox` for on-prem and on-cloud both and it should work?

Comment: No, the help describes a hybrid scenario.

Comment: You are going to need to use `Remove-RemoteMailbox` for your cloud shared mailboxes and `Remove-Mailbox` for the on prem shared mailboxes. I use both in our Hybrid Environment